# C# - XNA: Constantly checking keypresses

Tags: c#, xna, keypress

I've looked at all posts I could find about it and none of them seems to work for me. I want to constantly check for keypresses in the background for a game.

This is what I've made to try to get it to work, but it just won't.

```
namespace Base
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static int X = 0;
        public static int Y = 0;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                KeyboardState CurrentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

                if (CurrentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                {
                    MainClass.X += 1;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(X + ", " + Y);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pressing the Left key doesn't raise the X value, meaning there's no response.
I've read somewhere both that you can't check that constantly in Main or in a thread, but where should I check it then?

Comment: I should say that I'm new to C#.

Comment: Running a background thread to continually poll for input is usually a really bad idea in an XNA game. The CPU overhead for the thread and the complexity of ensuring that no data is corrupted from the time you tell the data to go to the GPU and it actually goes is usually not worth it. So since the Update method within an Xna game cycles 60 times per second, checking for input changes that often in the update method on the game thread is usually sufficient.

Comment: any one of these samples does it that way: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/?contenttype=0&devarea=7&platform=20&sort=1

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are new to C# then you are probably new to XNA also. XNA has a built in game loop functionality which calls its Update and Draw methods 60 times per second. Most game play logic should be either written into or called from the Update method. That means that whatever code you write into the Update method or gets called from the Update runs 60 times/sec. Generally, you call Keyboard.GetState() there. That means you are polling the keyboard 60/sec for any input.

It might be good for you to run through some beginner tutorials:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=xna+beginner+tutorial&qs=AS&pq=xna+begi&sk=AS1&sc=5-8&sp=2&cvid=6167E65B683F4A5EBB6488D48C8D011F&FORM=QBRE

Answer (score 0):

You should call it on Update as Update runs 60 times per second.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is that the namespace for keyboard input won't work in Console Applications. It is designed for C# XNA Framework, which is used for making games. I suggest switching to XNA for game programming, as Console Applications aren't designed for them.

Comment: 1. I've figured it out.
2. It wasn't a console application, I just printed it in the console to see the result.
3. Thank you anyway! :)